# Display message when user again trying to respond survey?

Tags: development, survey-list, survey, ootb

When User Try To Respond Survey Again ,Displaying Some Error message ,but i want to display A User Friendly Message...

I Read Some Article  But Not Found Any Solution Yet,help me

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the following solution. Add client side validation to determine whether the user has already responded to survey. If validation will fail then display user friendly message otherwise display the original response form. It will allow to avoid this exception to occur.

### Solution

Override JavaScript function for opening response form `NewItem2`

```
//override NewItem2 function
var NewItem2 = (function () {
    var NewItem2Orig = NewItem2;

    return function() {
        var evt = arguments[0];
        var url = arguments[1];

        //Read survey for current user to find out if he have already voted   
        readSurveyVotes(function(votesCount){
            //if voted then display custom message 
            if(votesCount > 0) {
                window.alert('You have already voted to this survey.');
            }
            //if not, call original function for opening response form
            else {
                NewItem2Orig(evt, url);
            } 
        });
    };

})();
```

Reading survey votes for current user

```
function readSurveyVotes(cbSurveyResult)
{
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Survey");
        var viewXml = '<View><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Author"/><Value Type="Integer"><UserID Type="Integer"/></Value></Eq></Where></View>';
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.set_viewXml(viewXml);
        var items = list.getItems(query);
        context.load(items);
        context.add_requestSucceeded(onLoaded);
        context.add_requestFailed(onFailure);
        context.executeQueryAsync();
        function onLoaded() {
            var voteCount = items.get_count();
            cbSurveyResult(voteCount)
        }
        function onFailure() {
            cbSurveyResult(null);
        }
}
```

### Usage

Save the code to JavaScript file and add reference to this file in overview.aspx page, like shown below:

```
<asp:content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:RssLink runat="server"/>
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration runat="server" name="Themable/survey.css">
    </SharePoint:CssRegistration>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/SE/SurveyOps.js"></script>
</asp:content>
```

[image]